# For Loop HTML Django

Tags: html, django

I have a for loop within my Django project, what I'am trying to do is the following :

```
If
morning_recess == True
lunch_recess == True
afternoon_recess == True

then the bootstrap tag in that field should be
<td><span class="badge badge-success">Success</span></td>
else
<td> None </td>
```

Here is my current code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Morning Recess</th>
    <th>Lunch Recess</th>
    <th>Afternoon Recess</th>
    <th>Earned At</th>

  </tr>

  <tr>
     {% for i in students_recess_today %}
     {% if i.morning_recess == True %}
     <td>{{i.student_ps }}</td>
     <td><span class="badge badge-success">Success</span></td>
     <td>{{i.lunch_recess}}</td>
     <td>{{i.afternoon_recess}}</td>
     <td>{{i.created_at}}</td>
     {% else %}
     <td>{{i.student_ps }}</td>
     <td>None</td> 
     <td>{{i.lunch_recess}}</td>
     <td>{{i.afternoon_recess}}</td>
     <td>{{i.created_at}}</td>
     {% endif %}
  </tr>

{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

The morning_recess works fine, however if i do another if statement after the following one, the order of my table gets all messed up. How do I write this correctly? Thank you

Comment: If you are intending multiple table rows, should the `<tr>` and `</tr>`  be inside the `{% for ...}` loop? Otherwise, you need to clarify the question. Also suggest browser "view page source" to see what html actually got generated. Generating some `<!-- html comments -->` will help with debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what "in that field" means, because in your example you have one **extra** column before the `morning_recess` column. But you can put `{% if %}` statements anywhere you want in the template, e.g.:

```
<td>
  {% if i.morning_recess %}
    <span class="badge badge-success">Success</span> 
  {% else %}
    <span>None</span>
  {% endif %}
</td>
<td>
  {% if i.lunch_recess %}
    <span class="badge badge-success">Success</span> 
  {% else %}
    <span>None</span>
  {% endif %}
</td>
<td>
  {% if i.afternoon_recess %}
    <span class="badge badge-success">Success</span> 
  {% else %}
    <span>None</span>
  {% endif %}
</td>
...
```

Also as other commenters suggest, your for loop should probably wrap the rows of your table (`<tr>...</tr>`), not the columns (`<td>`).

Answer (score 0):

You have the loop partially inside your `tr` element. It starts a row at the beginning and for every student adds the columns and ends a row, so it ends up looking like `<tr></tr></tr></tr>`.

You should move your `for` statement outside of the row, like so:

```html
...

{% for i in students_recess_today %}
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```